# Open Pdf with password protection in WP

Tags: wordpress, pdf, plugins

Is there a way to open a password-protected PDF file without asking password from user?

I mean, let the web enter the password itself. Then the user can read without entering the password again.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of doing so as far as I am aware.
The best work-around I can think of is to set a password on the page itself and check/automate that (e.g. use a GET if you "trust" the user, or a POST to disable direct links, think you can use some WP addons for this as well if it isn't already built in). This would make your pdf unsecured though when downloaded (though that might not matter as most can copy/paste/screenshot the pdf anyways).